# Error in PDF Export

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Here is my code snippet-

```
getResponse().setContentType(NAPSConstants.PDF_CONTENT_TYPE);
getResponse().setHeader(NAPSConstants.PDF_CONTENT_DISP, NAPSConstants.PDF_ATTACHMENT_FILE+getText("rcmid.details")+NAPSConstants.PDF_EXTN);
//Set the Page Size
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A3, 40, 40, 40, 40);

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(rcmDetailsCols.length); 
    for(RCMIDPartsDetailsDTO part : rcmidDTO.getPartsDetailsDTO()){
            table.addCell(part.getPartStatus().equals(NAPSConstants.Active) ? 
                    PDFHelper.dataCell( part.getPlantName(), PDFHelper.FONT_DATA) : 
PDFHelper.coloredDataCell( part.getPlantName(), PDFHelper.FONT_DATA));
table.addCell(part.getPartStatus().equals(NAPSConstants.Active) ?
                            PDFHelper.dataCell( part.getOemSupplierId(), PDFHelper.FONT_DATA):PDFHelper.coloredDataCell( part.getOemSupplierId(), PDFHelper.FONT_DATA));
table.addCell(PDFHelper.dataCellWithRowSpan( rcmidDTO.getPackSupplierId(), PDFHelper.FONT_DATA, rcmidDTO.getActiveRowSpan()+rcmidDTO.getPartsList.size()));

                }
                document.add(table);

    document.close();
```

//Helper methods

```
public static PdfPCell dataCell(String cellText, Integer fontSize)
    {
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
        if(cellText==null || cellText.compareTo("null")==0 || NAPSConstants.EMPTY_STRING.equals(cellText) || 
                cellText.equals(NAPSConstants.MINUS_ONE)){
            //cellText = NAPSConstants.TEXT_NA;
            cellText = NAPSConstants.EMPTY_STRING;
        }
        cell.setPhrase(new Phrase(cellText, new Font(Font.NORMAL, fontSize)));
        cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        return cell;
    }
public static PdfPCell coloredDataCell(String cellText, Integer fontSize)
    {
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
        if(cellText==null || cellText.compareTo("null")==0 || NAPSConstants.EMPTY_STRING.equals(cellText) || 
                cellText.equals(NAPSConstants.MINUS_ONE)){
            //cellText = NAPSConstants.TEXT_NA;
            cellText = NAPSConstants.EMPTY_STRING;
        }

        cell.setPhrase(new Phrase(cellText, new Font(Font.NORMAL, fontSize,0, new Color(255,0,0))));
        cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

        cell.setBackgroundColor(new Color(200, 200, 200));
        return cell;
    }

 public static PdfPCell dataCellWithRowSpan(String cellText, Integer fontSize, int rowspan)
    {
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
        cell.setRowspan(rowspan);   
        cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER); 
        cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
        if(cellText==null || cellText.compareTo("null")==0){
            //cellText = NAPSConstants.TEXT_NA;
            cellText = NAPSConstants.EMPTY_STRING;
        }

        cell.setPhrase(new Phrase(cellText, new Font(Font.NORMAL, fontSize)));
        return cell;
    }
```

I am not able to understand what the actual problem is.
I have two kinds of data 'Active'/'Inactive', therefore i have added ternary operator to change background color for inactive data.
The pdf export work perfectly fine for active data. But for inactive data the following is the exception.

```
ThreadMonitor W   WSVR0605W: Thread "WebContainer : 3" (0000001c) has been active for 754832 milliseconds and may be hung.  There is/are 1 thread(s) in total in the server that may be hung.
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.BidiLine.createArrayOfPdfChunks(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.BidiLine.createArrayOfPdfChunks(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.BidiLine.processLine(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPCell.getMaxHeight(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.getRowHeight(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.getRowHeight(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.getRowHeight(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.getRowHeight(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.getRowHeight(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.getRowHeight(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.getRowHeight(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.getRowHeight(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.getRowHeight(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.getRowHeight(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.getRowHeight(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.getRowHeight(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.getRowHeight(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.getRowHeight(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.getRowHeight(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.getRowHeight(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.getRowHeight(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.getRowHeight(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.getRowHeight(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.getRowHeight(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.getRowHeight(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.calculateHeights(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.setTotalWidth(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.ColumnText.goComposite(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.addPTable(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.add(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.Document.add(Unknown Source)
    at com.honda.naps.action.rcmid.RCMIDDetailsAction.rcmDetailsExportTOPDF(RCMIDDetailsAction.java:490)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
```

Also the java process takes upto 95% of CPU usage. The server becomes very slow. I have to stop the java process manually and restart server.

Comment: I see my name in your error messages. That means that you're using a version of iText that is 6 years old. That version is no longer supported. The current version is 5.5.6. Please upgrade.

Comment: Yes the application is more than 6 years old. By updating to latest version will this problem be solved ?

Comment: Are you saying that you have a 6 year old application and that you waited all this time to report the problem? Table functionality has been completely rewritten, so there is a high chance the problem will disappear.

Comment: No. New Modules are being prepared on the existing architecture and available jars. So while creating export functionality in the new module I faced this issue. I will try updating the jar and check, ideally the existing code should not get affected by jar update.

Comment: *Ideally the existing code should not get affected by jar update.* Er... if you wait 6 years to upgrade, you shouldn't expect that to be true!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved-

I was not able to update the jar because of dependencies of existing architecture.

But the real problem was with rowspan.
The rowspan was different for active/inactive parts.
After changing that logic the problem was solved.